# 'and what are the (...)'

Tags: grammar, word-order

I come across this sentence structure quite a lot, and every time again I wonder if it is actually grammatically correct. Example:

> In general, we know why groups mobilize in the EU, what strategies they tend to employ in the EU institutional setting, **and what are** their major points of access in the EU multilevel system and at the EU-level.

Is it exactly equivalent to ***and what their (...) are***?

When to use which?

Comment: Especially when concatenated with two other _wh_-clauses, the subject-auxiliary inversion in the last clause is simply ungrammatical. _Wh_-clauses (aka embedded questions or headless relatives) are formed like questions except that they don't invert subject and first auxiliary like questions do. The last clause should be _what their major points of access ... are._

Comment: You can see _why_ the inversion has been used – the 'are' would be almost lost after 'their major points of access in the EU multilevel system and at the EU-level'. Re-punctuating improves the situation somewhat: '...setting. And we also know what their major points of access – in the EU multilevel system and at the EU-level – are.'